# Integral $\int\frac{1}{x^2\log x}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am struggling to evaluate the following integral:

$$
\int\frac{1}{x^2\log x}dx.
$$

I have tried to solve it several times, but I wind up with the wrong answer.

Comment: The integral is non-elementary

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Substitute $u = \ln x \implies du=\frac1{x} \, dx$. Note that $x=e^u$.

Now, $$I = \int \frac1{x^2\ln x} \, dx$$ $$=\int \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \, du$$

Note that this is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), $-E_1(u)$.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you, sir.